# Node MongoDB: connection method callbacks never fire

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am copying an example literally from [MongoDB Node documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collection) (well almost literally, MongoDB's official documentation hasn't been updated to match [the recommendation to use MongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html), so I'm using MongoClient).

createcollection()'s callback never runs. I've had similar problems with other connection methods, eg, find(), findAndModify().

Copied straight of out the unit test:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(URL, function(err, db){
  // Establish connection to db
  log(1)
  assert.equal(null, err);

  // Grab a collection without a callback no safe mode
  var col1 = db.collection('test_correctly_access_collections');

  // Grab a collection with a callback but no safe operation
  db.collection('test_correctly_access_collections', function(err, col2) {
    log(2)
    assert.equal(null, err);

    // Grab a collection with a callback in safe mode, ensuring it exists (should fail as it's not created)
    db.collection('test_correctly_access_collections', {strict:true}, function(err, col3) {
      log(3)
      assert.ok(err != null);

      // Create the collection
      db.createCollection('test_correctly_access_collections', function(err, result) {
        log(4)
        // NEVER RUNS
      });
    });
  });
})
```

From other reading, I hear that MongoDB will queue queries if the connection is broken or slow.  But connect() worked fine, my DB is localhost and has <2Kb of documents.

My question is:

- How can I make collection methods work?
- Where can I read about the circumstances where queries will be queued? I've not seem mention of this in official docs I've been looking at.

**EDIT**: The code **will work exactly one time per URL**. Subsequent attempts to run the same code with the same URL will always fail. Changing the URL will work again, once per URL.

Comment: Not very helpful maybe, but when I run this with `URL='mongodb://localhost/bop'`, all callbacks get called.

Comment: The code works correctly (generally speaking, as a quick test verified it). The native driver for Node.JS doesn't queue, but MongooseJS does (wrapping NodeJS driver). Do you have other code outside of what you have in your question?

Comment: Thanks @WiredPrairie. This is my entire code - it's isolated in a single unit test, and there are no other tests. The app isn't using mongoose (I'm having enough trouble making straight mongo to work).

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson - actually that's helpful. See EDIT above.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Can you try re-running the code with the same URL? See EDIT above.

Comment: Second time around I get `assert.ok(err != null);` failing since the collection exists, so, no, I don't get to `4`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that might be it - the 'assert.ok(err != null);' was copied directly from the example, I'm not quite sure why they want to specifically check for not null as opposed to other truthy conditions.

Comment: The assert checks that `db.collection` with `strict` set fails when the collection doesn't exist. The problem is, second time you run it, it _does_ exist so you'll get null back as err, and the assert fails. The test basically assumes that the database is clean to run ok.

Comment: I'd think there would be a cleanup step: `db.dropCollection('test_correctly_access_collections', function(err, result) { /* check error */ });` after this completes as it's apparently designed to run once. (or the clean up might be to: `db.dropDatabase(function(err, result) {  db.close(); });`

Comment: Yeah @JoachimIsaksson I just noticed the 'strict' too (it's even in the comments, but I missed it the first time round). Man that was the wrong example to test with!

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yep adding setup and teardown stuff too (already wrote it and removed it until I can get this example going).

Comment: @WiredPrairie Sorry feel as if I've wasted your time here - I actually still have the problem (callbacks never fire) in other code, just this unit test was a bad example due to the 'strict' failure.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson See comment above - sorry.

Comment: @mikemaccana Any word on this? Having the same issue...

Comment: @hurshagrawal Yep, have added answer below. Current node-mongodb-native is broken and MongoDB Inc/10Gen know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was occurring because node-mongodb-native, the current 'stable' MongoDB driver, **silently wraps and throws away all exceptions**, including anything launched from a callback, no matter how many scopes down.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-mongodb-native/AZewJaX4YuE

The solution is to use the unstable 1.3.18 series mongodb package until 1.4 (which fixes the problem permanently) is stable.